# What is the best way to call functions over a network?

Tags: c++, function, network-programming, function-calls

I'm planning the network communications system for a program. The program is divided a client and a server class, but I might split them into separate programs if they get too big, and nothing else prevents it.

At the moment, all of the network communication is to call set and get functions on the server (of which their are about 500, and I expect to generate about 500-1,600 requests per second across eight clients in typical operations).

My current plan is to use a basic network API to send machine code inspired Opcodes to the server as a string, along with a few bytes of parameters, and have the server select the function and interpret the parameters using a massive `switch` statement.

However, with hundreds of possible function to call, this will get A) hard to read, and B)slow to implement. I'm also a bit concerned about the performance of large switch statements.

In light of that, could anyone confirm if this is the best way to implement function calls over a network, or tell me if there's a better way. I'd love a magic API that allows be to do something like `x = callServerFunc(server, function, parameter1...)` but my searches have not yet found such a library.

Comment: I think what you want to search for is "C++ RPC library"

Comment: Primarily opinion-based: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code from scratch. Feel free on how to do it.

Or you can use one of many ready mature technologies. Just google for [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model), [XPCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM) and so on. You can look at [Remote call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) in common. Or consider existing web-based technologies with different data formats. This is just a starting point. This tehnologies are mature but heavyweight. You'll need some knowledge and practice to start with them.

Comment: if you view the wiki page about RPC, there are so many choices. I can't list them all here.